# The simple and elegant way to express multiple for loop in python?

Tags: python

I have below code, would like to know what is the best simple and elegant way to express multiple for loop?

```
for x in range (10):
    for y in range (10):
        for z in range(10):
            if x+y+z=10:
                print (x,y,z)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There Are solutions.But This code is better readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

for x, y, z in product(range(10), range(10), range(10)):
    if x + y + z == 10:
        print(x, y, z)
```

To remove `range(10)` duplication use this:

```
for x, y, z in product(range(10), repeat=3):
```

EDIT: as [Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045800/tomerikoo) pointed out - in this specific case the code will be more flexible if you don't unpack the tuple:

```
for numbers in product(range(10), repeat=3):
    if sum(numbers) == 10:
        print(*numbers)
```

Comment: `product(range(10), times=3)`. The whole point of the `times` argument is to *avoid* repeating the range you want to use multiple times.

Comment: to make it more generic regardless of number of loops can be: `for prod in product(range(10), times=n): if sum(prod) == 10: print`. where `n` is the number of loops

Comment: @Tomerikoo No; again, `product` has a `times` argument to *avoid* that kind of convoluted argument construction.

Comment: I get: `TypeError: 'times' is an invalid keyword argument for product()` maybe you meant `repeat`

Comment: @chepner what if now you want to check it for 2 or 4 numbers? you need to go and add/remove variables and change the `if` expression. My suggestion simply makes it without the use of variables to better handle future changes

Comment: @Tomerikoo [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)